# why am I getting always "TypeError: callback is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback

Simple problem in React, I just want to make a simple callback to delay the loading of the data

```
function getSettings(callback) {
    getColors();
    callback();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getSettings().console.log(settings);
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);
```

and I get:

```
"TypeError: callback is not a function"
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're not passing your callback to getSettings(). If you're trying to pass the console.log, you could try:

```
getSettings(() => console.log(settings));
```